# Can two models belong_to each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have two models which are one-to-one to each other. A currently has one B.

Lately I encounter many cases where it is desirable if A keeps the id of B in order to simplify logic and boost performance. However I wonder if:

1. this is possible
2. would breach and convention
3. any thoughts really

---

UPDATE

I was wrong, the left outer join would not be benefited by the extra foreign key.

The only place I can think of is to find all A's which does not have B, an inner join is required on each of my 100000+ records. But if there is an id then I can know straight away which A has a B.

Comment: What performance issues are you seeing at the moment with the has_one/belongs_to setup?

Comment: currently I need to do a LEFT OUT JOIN for a query which needs to have different query logic based on the existence of B, together with a lot of other conditions.

Comment: Please detail your models and why you need circular reference.

Comment: Also, show the type of query you're trying to do. I'm sure there's a way to do it without the redundant information.

Comment: It should be possible to implement this, but would have to be very careful not to get infinite loops in areas like validations and filters. I agree with tsherif, that there should be a way to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible - you have to decide where to keep the foreign key. Would it make sense for you to use a joining through relationship and for both your existing models to be has_one through the join?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to put A id on B, i.e. denormalize.  This would allow you to figure out which A's without a B, and A's with a B.  This might be appropriate for reporting scenarios when B's don't move between A's often.